# How to dynamically reposition binary tree nodes visually

Tags: javascript, d3.js, binary-tree

I have been working with the following code: http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/7683252. This is a graphical representation of a tree. I have stripped away much of the code (the graceful labels), only allowing two nodes per parent, and changed the data structure to an array.

The only problem left now is the repositioning. The original code does that perfectly. But since I want a binary tree, I have let the user choose to insert a left or right child. The original reposition code animates the first child straight down from the parent, but that would be wrong in a binary tree. I want it to either go to the left or right.

```
reposition = function (v) {
    function repos(v) {
        var lC = getLeafCount(v.v),
            left = v.p.x; //parent's x-position

        v.c.forEach(function (d) {
            var vc = d; //saving reference of the child in parent object
            d = tree.getVerticeById(d.v); //actually fetching the child object
            var w = 0;
            if(d.d == 'right') { w += 15 * lC }
            if(d.d == 'left') { w -= 15 * lC }
            d.p = {x: left + w, y: v.p.y + tree.h}; //setting the position
            vc.p = d.p; //setting the child's pos in parent obj
            repos(d);
        });
    }
    repos(v[0]);
};
```

Some of the parts of my code are different from the original code, because I have changed the data structure as stated before. I have tried to comment the parts that may be confusing, but what is important is the math of the repositioning.

At first, this code seemed to work well (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjzOq.png). But after some testing I discovered a huge problem with the repositioning: the nodes crash with each other (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdQfy.png)!

**Conclusion:** I have tried to modify the original function to take the in mind the left and right positioning of nodes, but could not do it. I wrote this variant of the method which does, but it still has some problems as illustrated in the pictures. I would be thankful for some input in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually did a quick fix for this problem.

After running the reposition function as posted in the question, i ran another function which fixed the problem. The new function goes through all levels of the tree and checks if the nodes are too close together. If they are, the algorithm finds closest common ancestor, and increases the distance between its left and right children. After this, there is no more collisions between nodes.